# how to properly resolve a JS promise in an AngularJS application using odataresources.js library

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular app, I'm using odatasources.js library to get data from a public OData feed.
The following call returns a promise, which I want to be able to resolve, in order to gain access to the actual data returned by this promise:

```
var myModule = angular.module("MyModule",['ODataResources']);
myModule.controller("MyController",function($scope,$odataresource){
    $scope.results = 
        $odataresource("http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products")
        .odata()
        .filter('UnitPrice','>',10)
        .filter('Discontinued',true)
        .orderBy('UnitsInStock','asc')
        .expand('Category')
        .query();
});
```

What I would like to do (for starters), is to iterate over the returned data, and simple log it onto the console:

```
angular.forEach($scope.results, function(value, key) {
        console.log(key + '   ' + value);
    });
```

As it stands now, $scope.results is an un-resolved promise.

What is the proper syntax to have this promise resolved, and to iterate over the actual returned data?

Here is my current fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/gmqvq9fx/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by passing in a callback to the `query()` method. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmqvq9fx/5/)

```
var myModule = angular.module("MyModule",['ODataResources']);
myModule.controller("MyController",function($scope,$odataresource){
    $scope.results = 
        $odataresource("http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products")
        .odata()
        .filter('UnitPrice','>',10)
        .filter('Discontinued',true)
        .orderBy('UnitsInStock','asc')
        .expand('Category')
        .query(function(data) {
          console.log('success');
          console.log(data);
          angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
            console.log(key + '   ' + value);
          });
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('There was an error: ', err);
        });
});
```